# How to add a view to navigator right after browsing the url to the view in Vaadin

Tags: java, view, vaadin, navigator

I have a page that require some object values from another view. when I add the view in the main UI like this :

```
getNavigator().addView(Home.NAME, Home.class);
getNavigator().addView(Profile.NAME, Profile.class);
```

It instantiate the Profile view and return NullpointerException because some object are not filled yet. 
For some internal reasons I don't want to fill the object after that profile has been instantiated. I want to get my object first and then add the view to the navigator when the user browse to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the vaadin api for [Navigator](https://vaadin.com/api/7.1.13/com/vaadin/navigator/Navigator.html) class you can see that you can use an overloaded method addView that does what you want, one of those take an instance of your view instead of a class. Your pofile class must me assignable from View though.

```
Profile profile = new Profile();
// do more stuff with profile
getNavigator().addView(Profile.NAME, profile);
```